# Implementing Poetry inside Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-poetry

I currently Have a Docker container I would like to start using poetry inside it.
I have looked at several documentations and examples but unsure if this would be the correct case for me. Poetry and its dependencies are already installed within the project.

The previous dockerfiles is

```
FROM python:3.9 as base
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
          binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin \
          netcat postgresql-client sudo curl \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && mkdir /code

ADD requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt

FROM base

ADD requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

I have added..

```
FROM python:3.9 as base
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

From base as builder

ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.0.0 \

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
          binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin \
          netcat postgresql-client sudo curl \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && mkdir /code

ADD requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt

RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --version $POETRY_VERSION
RUN python -m venv /venv

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /code/
COPY . /code

FROM base as final

ADD requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Is this the correct way of implementing poetry inside docker containers? How would I test this out?

Answer (score 0):

Three main things are important while it's poetry,

```
RUN pip3 install -U pip poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
```

1. Install the poetry
2. Set not to create a virtualenv
3. Install the packages.

### How you can test.

- You can just build the Dockerfile to create an image.
  So, `docker build -t tag_name_your_project .`

Answer (score 0):

A working [I think] poetry `Dockerfile` for your original using `pipx` appears below. A working poetry install using `curl` is [here](https://github.com/Graphlet-AI/graphml-class/blob/main/Dockerfile).

Fill in the values for ${POETRY_VERSION}, ${USER}, ${UID} and ${GID}.

```
FROM python:3.9 as base
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
          binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin \
          netcat postgresql-client sudo curl \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && mkdir /code

# Install pipx so we can install isolated poetry system wide
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --user pipx && \
    python3 -m pipx ensurepath

# Now install poetry to install our dependencies
RUN pipx install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

# Copy our poetry configuration files to know what to install
COPY --chown=${UID}:${GID} pyproject.toml "/home/${USER}/work/"
COPY --chown=${UID}:${GID} poetry.lock    "/home/${USER}/work/"

# Install our package requirements via poetry. No venv. Squash max-workers error.
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry config installer.max-workers 10 && \
    poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root -vvv && \
    poetry cache clear pypi --all -n

COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```